# Objective-C Moving Items Between Arrays (Memory Management)

Tags: objective-c

Is there any practical difference between the following two code snippets:

```
NSObject * obj = [[_mutableArrayOne objectAtIndex:i] retain];
[_mutableArrayOne removeObject:obj];
[_mutableArrayTwo addObject:obj];
[obj release];
```

and

```
NSObject * obj = [_mutableArrayOne objectAtIndex:i];
[_mutableArrayTwo addObject:obj];
[_mutableArrayOne removeObject:obj];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the extra retain/release cycle that you ask it to do.

It might have some performance impact inside a loop of time-sensitive processing?

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I thought.

Comment: removeObject remove all occurrences - in second case you will not have the 'objec' in the mutable array any more .... see my answer...

Comment: This is blatantly not true.  In the second case, there is a small window of time when the object is in *both* arrays.  In a multithreaded environment, this may be a problem (conversely, having the object in no arrays might also be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

Other than the need to call `retain` and `release` twice instead of once, no. The end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to own the object in the index 'i' then remove object from array and then you can add it back to the array in the later stage of the project.

I suggest option 2 should be careful : the object will not be in the array any more.

The result is different -- Option 1 you will have the 'object' in mutable array and in option 2 'object' will not be in array (removeObject remove all occurrences)

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you properly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: removeObject remove all occurrences

in your second case you add the occurrence of the 'obj' first then there will be duplicate entry in the array then you ask to remove the 'obj' occurrence using 'removeObject' which will remove all occurrence(apple apple documentation) of the 'obj' in the array so no more 'obj' is not present in the array

but in 1 case obj will be present in the end of the array.

Comment: sorry i missed some detail actually both are same

Answer (score 1):

Both are same with respect to `Memory Management` and programming logic. Only in the first case you have to operate a pair of extra `retain/release` operation.